# How to calculate 5x+y expression in C with special instruction?

Tags: c, overflow

I need to calculate `5x + y` in C program. I want to do it by implementing the `calc5plusy` function taking `x, y` and pointer to result as arguments.

`calc5plusy` must return 1 if it detected overflow. TI need to cast x and y to 64-bit types (long long unsigned int), perform the calculation, and determine if the result is greater than the maximum size of an unsigned int. If overflow is detected, I need to return a nonzero value. If overflow is not detected update the answer pointer, and return 0.

I need to test my function in detail to make sure that it properly handles all possible 32-bit inputs, and provides correct output.

Here's what I have so far to get it started but because I haven't ever written C program, I'm writing it as a psedocode within wherever I have // signs. Please help as I'm lost as to where how would this be interpreted in C and/or if I'm even doing this right. This is basically my very first C program. Your help will be appreciated!

```
#include <stdio.h>

    // return_type name(arguments) {activities;}


    int main(void)
    {
        unsigned int overflow, answer;
        printf("an unsigned int is %lu bits!\n", 8 * sizeof (unsigned int));

        long long unsigned int x, y;

        overflow = calc5xplusy(/* Put your own arguments here */);

        // if x < 429
        // then 2^31-1-5*x *tells how large y may be so that there will be no overflow

        if (overflow) {
            printf("Overflow occurred!\n");
            return 1;
        } else {
            printf("Success: %u\n", answer);
            return 0;
        } 
    }
```

EDIT: 
@Anton Savin thank you for your suggestion! It did help! Here is what I got as a final result of this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned int calc5xplusy(unsigned int x, unsigned int y, unsigned int *answer);

const unsigned int BIGGEST = 4294967295;

int main(void)
{
    unsigned int overflow, answer;

    printf("an unsigned int is %lu bits!\n", 8 * sizeof (unsigned int));

    overflow = calc5xplusy(5, 3, &answer);

    if (overflow) {
        printf("Overflow occurred!\n");
        return 1;
    } else {
        printf("Success: %u\n", answer);
        return 0;
    } 
}
unsigned int calc5xplusy(unsigned int x, unsigned int y, unsigned int *panswer)
{
    long long unsigned int value;
    value = (long long unsigned int)x * 5 + (long long unsigned int)y;
    if (value <= BIGGEST) {
        *panswer = (unsigned int)value;
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no other way to test your function than manually create a set of test cases which you check for correctness yourself, and run your function on all of them, comparing the outcome with the desired result. This can be done for example like this:

```
typedef struct Test {
    int x;
    int y;
    int overflow;
} Test;

Test tests[] = {
    {1, 2, 0},
    {1000000000, 1000000000, 1},
    // Add more tests here
};

numTests = sizeof(tests)/sizeof(tests[0]);
for (i = 0; i < numTests; ++i) {
    int res, overflow;
    overflow = calc5xplusy(tests[i].x, tests[i].y, &res);
    if (overflow != tests[i].overflow)
        printf("Test #%d failed\n", i);
}
```

[Online Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/be926ad099506f65)